# d3js - How to insert things in order?

Tags: d3.js

Say I want an HTML list of sorted names from a sorted array.

Most of the examples for d3.js that refer to sorting do so by *positioning* arbitrarily ordered nodes according to their order. But I need the nodes to be created in order.

Here's an example of the problem (as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emgjh0j7/)).

```
var d = ['fred', 'wilma'];
draw(d); // Gives list with 2 li elements, fred, wilma

d.unshift('barney');
draw(d); // Gives 3 elements, fred, wilma, barney

function draw(d) {
    lis = d3.select('ul').selectAll('li').data(d, identity);
    lis.enter().append('li').text(identity);
}

// just handy
function identity(d){return d;};
```

The output of this is a list: *fred, wilma, barney* but I want a list *barney, fred, wilma*.

I understand *why* this code does this (I'm just using append on the container, so new items always go at the end), but is there a fancy d3js way to preserve the order of the list of data?

Comment: See my answer below :) if that is helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, turns out it's rather trivial!

Simply call [`.order()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#order) after adding the data.

Updated example:

```
var d = ['fred', 'wilma'];
draw(d); // Gives list with 2 li elements, fred, wilma

d.unshift('barney');
draw(d); // Gives 3 elements, fred, wilma, barney

function draw(d) {
    lis = d3.select('ul').selectAll('li').data(d, identity);
    lis.enter().append('li').text(identity);
    lis.order();
}

// just handy
function identity(d){return d;};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emgjh0j7/1/

Comment: Updated link for [D3 V4's `Selection.order()` documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_order) - and if you want the stacking order of the D3 elements to be sorted differently to the order of the data array, you can use [`Selection.sort()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_sort)

Answer (score 0):

You have to redraw whole view when you are making any change to array. when you are using `unshift` to add an element it is getting added as first element of array but it is not re-drawing whole array again but only newly added elements at end :) here is code you can try.

```
var d = ['fred', 'wilma'];

// Gives list with 2 li elements, fred, wilma
draw(d);

// prepend an element to our sorted list and redraw.
window.setTimeout(function() {
    d.unshift('barney');
    draw([""]); // Removing previous array to redraw.
    draw(d);
    console.log(d); // Print array order in console.
}, 1000);


function draw(d) {
    lis = d3.select('ul').selectAll('li').data(d, identity);
    lis.enter().append('li')
       .text(identity)
       .style({height:'0', overflow:'hidden'})
       .transition().duration(1000).style({height:'2rem'});
    lis.exit().remove(); // Removing previous array to redraw.
}

// handy
function identity(d){return d;};
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. Obviously this example is trivial - 3 very simple elements. My use case has very complex (expensive to draw) elements, and hundreds of them, so I only want to create when there's something new to create. I need a way to find the correct place to do the insertion for the new entries.

Comment: Can you have a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376626/keeping-order-in-d3-data` this is very helpful answer I think :)