# What is d3 accessor function within data node for?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have encountered a very strange data connection in an example code in d3.
So I would like to ask you guys what this accessor function does.

Normally, 
Data links I have seen so far were like

```
d3.selectAll('something').data('somedata').enter().append('something').attr('x',function(d){})
```

Accessor to the data was used in its attributes.I haven't seen the cases using accessor function, which is function(d) within data() side.

However, in the example I attached below, is using the accessor function in the data() side.

What is this and why does this code was written in this way?

Full code link:
https://jsfiddle.net/soonk/o8a5np20/

The code part that I'm curious about is

```
function restart() {

  // Apply the general update pattern to the nodes.
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id;});

  node.exit().transition()
      .attr("r", 0)
      .remove();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The second parameter of `.data()` allows for a function to bind data with a particular node, by default D3 uses index (the 2nd data array item is bound to the 2nd selected DOM element), but if you have changing numbers of elements (or a stable number of elements, but data points that are dropped while others are added), then the id function lets you keep specific data bound to specific elements. I'll see if there's a better explanation out there.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17377087/7106086) answer might be useful, or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37514090/7106086), the first is by Mike Bostock, creator of D3. These answers are older but still relevant (note there are changes to the update/enter cycle since v3, but these are immaterial to the key function's functionality).

Comment: Hi Andrew. You answer is crystal clear for me. Especially, your mentioning about array structure makes me see the things behind the scene very clearly. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @AndrewReid Especially, your first reply is stunning... however many times I read, it's really... truly...clear......

Comment: Thanks, I'll just add that the key function must return a string - you can't use a datum that is an object as the key directly.

Comment: You may want to check the official documentation about `.data`'s key function: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/#selection_data